# NTC Thermistor Life span?

Tags: thermistor

is there a lifespan of how long an NTC thermistor should last when used as a current inrush limiter? was thinking it should go over 10 years but not sure?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Good question  +1 .I always bypass my NTCs  when doing high current           so they dont permanently run hot .It vis said that the resistance can change over temp/time .Hopefully there will be some hard data in the answers

Comment: As Rohat said, this will depend on the actual device and be part of what the manufacturer, and only them, will tell you

Comment: Is there a quality difference between manufacturers?